# Error in 1 file but not another (same XML code)?

Tags: android, xml

**Problem**:
I made a axml file and copied the xml from another file into the new one.
For some reason I am getting an error in the new one, but not the original, even though the code is the same. So the error message doesn't even make sense. Im lost at what to do, as usually there actually is something invalid when this error happens, but that seems impossible in this case

**Error**:
Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

**Environment**:
Xamarin.Android - axml - in Visual Studio 2022

**Thoughts**:
Any alternate troubleshooting ideas here?
And on a side note, are there tools that can parse XML and see where the problem is? I know visual studio says its at line 140, but I dont see anything wrong there. And when ive gotten this error in the past and there was an issue, it wasn't actually at the line that visual studio said it was

**Code**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/table_29th_Col2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_span="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="29th of each month If month does not have 29 days, then the last day of that month (ex: Jan 29th, Feb 28th, Mar 29th, etc…)"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="15"/>
```

Top of file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: In the code you've shown us, the namespace prefix `android` is undeclared. This is a common problem when cutting-and-pasting XML. As to your other question, there's a vast range of XML editors available. The best ones, of course, are not free.

Comment: I have this at the top of the file   - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: Well, the problem appears to be in the part of the XML that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. The problem was there was an invisible character in the xml. It didnt show in Visual Studio, but I saw it in an outside diffmerge tool. It likely came from copying that text from microsoft excel into visual studio